# How to optimize in react js while working with useReducer, looped over state which is passed to child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-reducer

I am trying to create to To-Do list.

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UseReducerToDo/>
    </div>
  );
}

const { useReducer, useState } = React;

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  return [...state, { id: Date.now(), ToDo: action, completed: false }];
};

function UseReducerToDo() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);
  const [Todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const addToTODO = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(Todo);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={addToTODO}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={Todo}
          onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
      </form>
      {state.length > 0
        ? state.map((todo) => <DispToDo key={todo.id} todo={todo} />)
        : "no pending items"}
    </div>
  );
}

function DispToDo({ todo }) {
  console.log("DispToDo", todo);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {todo.ToDo + "->"} status {todo.completed ? "done" : "pending"}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Now, the code compiles and works fine. The issue is regarding performance.

when the application runs
[image: initial screen]

when the first element is added and submitted
[image: after first element added]

Now the actual issue pops up
[image: after each keypress]

I have figured out that each keypress in the text box refreshes the child component `DispToDo`. That is evident, as logs in the console added up for every keypress.

There is no change in the `state` but there is refresh in `DispToDo`.

Is there any way to optimize this?

Comment: Memoize `DispToDo` component (`React.memo`). If you put this code in codesandbox I can show an example.

Comment: @DennisVash I converted the code into a runnable stack snippet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can memoize your `state.map()` with a [`useMemo()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usememo) hook:

```js
const todos = useMemo(() => (
  state.map((todo) => <DispToDo key={todo.id} todo={todo} />)
), [state]);
```

See below for a full demo:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <UseReducerToDo/>
    </div>
  );
}

const { useMemo, useReducer, useState } = React;

const reducer = (state, action) => {
  return [...state, { id: Date.now(), ToDo: action, completed: false }];
};

function UseReducerToDo() {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, []);
  const [Todo, setTodo] = useState("");

  const addToTODO = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(Todo);
  };
  
  const todos = useMemo(() => (
    state.map((todo) => <DispToDo key={todo.id} todo={todo} />)
  ), [state]);

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={addToTODO}>
        <input
          type="text"
          value={Todo}
          onChange={(e) => setTodo(e.target.value)}
        ></input>
      </form>
      {state.length > 0 ? todos : "no pending items"}
    </div>
  );
}

function DispToDo({ todo }) {
  console.log("DispToDo", todo);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>
        {todo.ToDo + "->"} status {todo.completed ? "done" : "pending"}
      </p>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thats actually render the whole list on state change, instead of only rendering the specific todo item

Answer (score 1):

Try rendering a [memoized component](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo):

```
const MemoDispToDo = React.memo(DispToDo);

// ...
.map(todo => <MemoDispToDo key={todo.id} todo={todo} />)
```

[image: Edit React Template (forked)]